# Titanium.Network.online is not working on android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Titanium.Network.online does not yield any result on android emulator, may I know what is wrong? I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to tiapp.xml
Below are my code. Thanks.

```
$('#login').click(function(){
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  Titanium.App.fireEvent('loginNow', {e:email, p:password});
  return false;
});     

Titanium.App.addEventListener('loginNow', function(data){
if(!Titanium.Network.online){
  Titanium.API.info('connection is not ok');
}else{
  Titanium.API.info('connection is ok');
  var signingin = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator({
    message: "Signing in.."
  });
  signingin.show();
}
});
```

Comment: What does the following report? Ti.API.info('network status: ' + Titanium.Network.online);

Answer (score 0):

We have found that the online attribute seems to work.  One other item you can look at is the network type from Titanium.Network.networkType.  It will return one of the following Titanium.Network constants:

- NETWORK_LAN
- NETWORK_MOBILE
- NETWORK_WIFI
- NETWORK_UNKNOWN
- NETWORK_NONE

If you get none or unknown, that may be another indicator that something is amiss.